# Windows 7 Missing Updates

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I'm sure there are windows 7 updates missing on my pc despite the fact it is up to date but the look is a lot different to the ones on google images.

Is there anyway of finding out as the update checker can be sometimes quite unreliable?

**What mine looks like**

[image]

**What it should look like**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfJ91.png

Comment: What is the last cumulative update that was installed?  I have found Windows Update is very reliable, you will need to be more specific,on what you mean the "look is a lot different" since that statement is not clear.

Comment: The last cumulative update was a security update for Internet Explore 11 realised 13th September 2016. The layout on the top right corner looks a lot different than it should be.

Comment: You will need to provide a screenshot, the look and feel of Windows 7, has never been updated.  However, it sounds like you are not even running Windows 7 Service Pack 1, which will indeed be a requirement to receive any update from the Windows Update catalog.  *I also wanted the KB number itself.*

Comment: You need to make sure you have Windows 7 Service Pack 1 installed.  After you have confirmed that, install [KB4490628](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4490628) and [KB4474419](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4474419),  After you do that updates should be seen.

Comment: What do you believe in incorrect in that screenshot?  It looks identical to my fully patched Windows 7 VM I have at home.

Comment: Yes I run Windows 7 32Bit On Virtual Box

Comment: I understand you run Windows 7.  However, what is not clear, is what you believe is different about your Windows Update window.

Comment: Not just that on the windows updater page all of them have got that. I have highlighted the error on the image on the top right coner

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  Please explain in detail what you are you talking about.  If you were missing those two required updates, and you have confirm that Windows Update is now working, just indicate that is the case.  I am only interested in writing a better more detail answer to the question you asked.

Comment: On the image that I uploaded the right top corner with the window options are circled they are different to what they should look like. How do I Fix It?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in that screenshot.  Your Windows Update looks exactly the way it's suppose to.

Comment: I have edited my question with a image that compares the two. Please have a close look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway of finding out as the update checker can be sometimes quite unreliable?

Windows Update is indeed reliable.  The reason updates are not being discovered is due to your system missing required updates.  One of those required updates is [KB4490628](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4490628) which is a Servicing stack update (SSU).

> Updates for legacy Windows versions will require that SHA-2 code
> signing support be installed. The support released in March
> [KB4474419](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4474419) and [KB4490628](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4490628) will be required in order to
> continue to receive updates on these versions of Windows.
>
> All legacy Windows updates signatures changed from SHA-1 and dual
> signed (SHA-1/SHA-2) to SHA-2 only at this time.

You also are missing [KB4474419](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4474419) which is required in order to support the migration to SHA-2.

> Starting in early 2019, the migration process to SHA-2 support began in stages, and support will be delivered in standalone updates.

Source: [2019 SHA-2 Code Signing Support requirement for Windows and WSUS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4472027/2019-sha-2-code-signing-support-requirement-for-windows-and-wsus)

> The following required updates must be installed and then the device restarted before installing any update released August 13, 2019 or later. The required updates can be installed in any order and do not need to be reinstalled, unless there is a new version of the required update.
>
> - Servicing stack update (SSU) [KB4490628](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4490628). If you use Windows Update, the required SSU will be offered to you automatically.
> - SHA-2 update [KB4474419](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4474419) released September 10, 2019. If you use Windows Update, the required SHA-2 update will be offered to you automatically.

**Windows 7 Service Pack 1 is obviously required in order to install [KB4490628](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4490628) and [KB4474419](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4474419)**

Comment: @harrymc - You have indicated that I am missing some critical information but have failed to provide specifics.  I cannot improve my answer if vague statements like "you missed out on the most important one" is the only feedback that is provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify your installed updates against Microsoft's catalog.
You will find it at
[Microsoft Update Catalog for Windows 7](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=windows+7).

But the better solution for updating Windows 7 is to install the
[Convenience rollup update for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3125574/convenience-rollup-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2).

Follow the instructions in the above link.
This will get you all the updates in one go, so you don't need to worry
about missing ones or to trust Windows Update.
This update is installed offline, not via Windows Update, so you cannot
miss out on anything.

Comment: That could take several hours.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how the author is suppose to do anything with this answer.  There are literally hundreds of updates that will be listed compatible with Windows 7.  Only a handful of those updates should actually be installed since the majority of the updates will have already been superseded by newer updates several dozen times.  *So what updates specifically should the author focus on trying to install?*

Comment: @harrymc - If the author were to attempt to install any of the current updates they would be told their system isn't applicable due the missing the SSU.  While the suggestion to install the rollup update is helpful, I am not sure, it will completely solve the author's current problem by itself.

Comment: @Ramhound: I added more instructions. This will solve all his problems in one go. With your cumbersome method, it's unsure what he will have, or not have, at the end. Again, downvoting instead of waiting for the final version of my answer, is diverting the poster from the best solution.