# How to easily install 150+ updates on a 32 bit windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates, 32-bit, asus-laptop

I have an old Asus laptop with windows 7 32 bit, and after fixing various driver problems, now I find myself with 150+ windows updates to install.
Is there a way to install all of them in the right order in a much easier and faster way?
Thanks

Comment: There is no simple way to update an outdated copy of Windows 7 other than allowing Windows Update to install all the missing updates., eventually you will catch up to a point, where Windows 7 had monthly cumulative updates.

Comment: Having them check in with a WSUS server, settings GPOs with applicable settings, etc. may help speed it up a bit. There are some remote commands you could run against them as well depending on your environment or configuration, but not sure what's worth what amount of time configuring in your case. Good luck!!

Comment: If you can find a later version of Win7 that you *trust*, you can replace the existing installation and bypass some updates. It's surprising , that MS still provides those old updates! To keep a 32-bit Acer D250 alive, and improve performance, I switched to Ubuntu 16.04, and later updated to 18.04 LTS (there is no 18.04 installer, BTW), and there are *still* security updates for that: https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-18-04-eol-for-devices . Ubuntu has no new 32-bit releases, but some other Linux distros do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 7 Missing Updates](https://superuser.com/questions/1499255/windows-7-missing-updates)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can skip the task of installing hundreds of individual updates because the [convenience rollup update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/convenience-rollup-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-da9b2435-2a1c-e7fa-43f5-6bfb34767d65) was released before the introduction of the monthly cumulative updates to bring windows 7 based OSes on that level. So you follow the prerequisites listed there, basically a recent servicing stack update, then after the convenience rollup you can jump right to the most recent monthly cumulative update.